# Strange characters after JSON

Tags: c++, json, arduino, esp8266, uart

I have an application that gets the Arduino Nano information and sends it to ESP-01 via UART. The ESP-01 send this to MQTT.

NANO CODE:

```cpp
#include "DHTesp.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define gasSensor A1
#define dhtPin 5
#define rain A2
#define soil A3
#define ldr A4

DHTesp dht;

void setup() {

 Serial.begin(115200);
 pinMode(gasSensor, INPUT);
 pinMode(rain, INPUT);
 pinMode(soil, INPUT);
 pinMode(ldr, INPUT);

 digitalWrite(dhtPin, LOW);

 dht.setup(dhtPin, DHTesp::DHT11);
}

void loop() {

  delay(dht.getMinimumSamplingPeriod());

  float humidity = dht.getHumidity();
  float temperature = dht.getTemperature();

  DynamicJsonBuffer jBuffer;
  JsonObject& measure = jBuffer.createObject();
  JsonObject& data = jBuffer.createObject();

  measure["gas"] = analogRead(gasSensor);
  measure["humidity"] = humidity;
  measure["temperature"] = temperature;
  measure["heatindex"] = dht.computeHeatIndex(temperature, humidity, false);
  measure["rain"] = analogRead(rain);
  measure["soil"] = analogRead(soil);
  measure["ldr"] = analogRead(ldr);

  data["measure"] = measure;

  data.printTo(Serial);
}
```

ESP-01 CODE:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const char* mqtt_server = "0.0.0.0";
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

char mystr[100];

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("", "");
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected to IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
}

void loop() {

  if (client.connect("ESP")) {
    Serial.println("STATUS MQTT-ESP: OK");
    while (true) {
      Serial.readBytes(mystr, 108);
      client.publish("esp", mystr);
      delay(1000);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("STATUS MQTT-ESP: OFF");
  }
}
```

But, I'm getting strange characters into MQTT:

[image]

And, at the connection between NANO <-uart-> Computer, the JSON is normal:

[image]

Someone could help me?
Thanks.

Comment: TLDR (maybe I'm wrong): check proper use of the `'\0'` string terminator

Comment: and, how can I do that? @pmg

Comment: Probably there's a mistake in the ` WiFi.begin(", "");` reported code. A missing `"`, maybe?

Comment: oh gosh, true! I had clear the information on SSID and PASS to paste here and clean this character. Sorry and thanks, Roberto.

Comment: Have tryed using ArduinoJson 6 instead of ArduinoJson 6 ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio I'll try.

Comment: `char mystr[100]; ... Serial.readBytes(mystr, 108);` Where do you expect the extra 8 bytes to go?

Comment: I do that to get all JSON characters. I don't know how to get the exact length of JSON. :(
@Gerhardh

Comment: That is not related to any JSON stuff. You have an array of 100 bytes but you tell the `readBytes` method that the buffer is 108 bytes. It doesn't matter if those bytes are JSON string or anything else.

Comment: @phoenixstudio I tried to put version 6 of Arduino JSON and I get this error: 

`error: DynamicJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6
   DynamicJsonBuffer jBuffer;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                 
exit status 1
DynamicJsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6`

Comment: @vicpb it means you should upgrade your libs, the newer version is more stable, it is up to decide if it worth the troulbe

Comment: @Gerhardh great point. So, how many bytes I can put on that?

Comment: @phoenixstudio but, I upgraded and I got this error.

Comment: How many bytes can go in an array of 100 bytes? Uhm... 100? Of course this is including terminating 0 byte.

Comment: hmmm... Gotcha! Tks @Gerhardh.

Comment: Perhaps if you hadn't deleted your last question after people tried to help you you would have made more progress on this already.

Comment: Hey @romkey, how can I get the JSON correctly?

Comment: Correctly separating your frames is a different topic. You should open another question for that. If the extra characters are solved now, you might accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am basing this answer on a bit of assumptions as I don't have an Arduino at hand.

You send your data like this:

```cpp
data.printTo(Serial);
```

This sends the string holding the formatted JSON data. This does not include the terminating 0 byte.

Then you receive it like this:

```cpp
char mystr[100];
...
        while(true){
            Serial.readBytes(mystr, 108);
            client.publish("esp", mystr);
            delay(1000);
        }
```

This has multiple errors:

1. You do not care if you got any bytes at all. The method returns the number of bytes but you do not handle the return value at all. If you got 0 bytes within the timeout value, you will just send the previous message again instead of waiting for valid data.
2. You cannot put 108 bytes into memory location of 100 bytes.
3. You put an array of `char` into the `publish` method that does not contain any termination. How should that method know how many characters are really part of the string?

Try this:

```cpp
        while(true){
            size_t num = Serial.readBytes(mystr, sizeof(mystr)-1);
            mystr[num] = 0;
            client.publish("esp", mystr);
            delay(1000);
        }
```

4. You do not have any protocol that allows you to detect when a message starts or ends. UART communiation is a byte stream without any boundaries for datagrams. You must ensure that you know what belongs to a message and what does not. This also means that you can never know if you have a complete message in your receive bufffer or an incomplete or even more than one message. It's up to you to detect and split messages. Fixing this is a bit more complex. I can only give some hints what you need to do.

a) Detect message boundaries:

- You might send some terminator like `\n`, 0 or similar after each JSON string and scan for this extra byte on receiver side.
- Or you can send the length of the string before you send the string.
- You could also just check on receiver side when you have a matching pair of `{}`. This would not require any change on sender side.

b) Collect messages:

- Call your read function as long as it takes until you detect the end of a string.
- You might need to use intermediate buffer to collect multiple read buffers.

c) Forward messages:

- As soon as you detected the end of a message, forward it via `publish` function.
- Then move the remaining content of your collection buffer to the start of that buffer.
- If you immediately find the end of another message, repeat that step.
- If you don't find any complete message, continue to collect more data until the next message is complete.

Comment: Ok works the strange characters are not anymore, but I'm getting the JSON broken. 

`tindex":26.97,"rain":714,"soil":715,"ldr":2}}{"measure":{"gas":246,"humidity":42.00,"temperature":2`

Comment: You don't have any detection of message boundaries. Updated my answer. You might need to read some more basic tutorials about serial communication.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I appreciate the attention.